# How to attach event listener to Mapbox GL Geocoder search input? (Vue app)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mapbox

So it seems like a simple thing but I'm having issues attaching an event listener to the Mapbox GL Geocoder search input in a Vue app.

Really I'm looking to do something as simple as this.

```
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  alert('clicked!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To check for click on an element in vue use

`<element-name @click="myMethod()" />`